# How to use a single webView for multiple buttons

Tags: android, android-webview

I want to open 5 web views with an `OnClickListener` button
but I want to do it in a single webView implementation
without using separate webView activities for each button.

Comment: Could you expand on the desired functionality?

Comment: I want to open let 5 websites inside my app.. for that i have to impliment 5 buttons with onclick listener and they will be intented to a webview after user clicks on it.. each webview will be a single activity so can i use 1 webview activity for all 5 buttons onclick event

Answer (score 2):

It's quite easy to implement:

Start with your onClickListeners, use the "URL" key or anything you like as long as they are the same everywhere and put your url as value:

```
 mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent webviewIntent = new Intent(MyActivity.this,MyWebViewActivity.class);
            webviewIntent.putExtra("URL","http://www.google.com");
            startActivity(webviewIntent);
        }
    });
```

In your MyWebViewActivity you can get that value in the onCreate and load that url.

```
String url = getIntent().getStringExtra("URL");
mWebView.loadUrl(url);
```